# NetLogo BehaviorSpace crashing when using R extension

Tags: r, netlogo, behaviorspace

I'm running a model of animal home ranges on my machine. I've added the R-extension to my NetLogo code to calculate minimum convex polygons for each home range. When I run the model in BehaviorSpace on multiple cores, NetLogo will simply disappear (i.e., stop running) after several time steps. I've tried it in 5.04 and 5.1 and the same happens.  The model does run properly in BehaviorSpace if I choose 1 core instead of the 4 available on my machine. It also runs properly if I turn off the R-extension. Is there something I should be doing? I'd like to run it on a virtual machine with multiple cores eventually.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006c7252f7, pid=6620, tid=4264
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b20) (build 1.7.0_65-b20)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [R.dll+0x252f7]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000012b64000):  JavaThread "JobThread" [_thread_in_native, id=4264, stack(0x0000000013c90000,0x0000000014490000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x0000000000000010

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000021f6ebd8, RBX=0x00000000221e2f30, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x000000001e28fb70
RSP=0x0000000014487df0, RBP=0x00000000068f0788, RSI=0x000000006c9dc2c0, RDI=0x000000006c95da70
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000000001
R12=0x00000000221e2f38, R13=0x000000006c95db40, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x00000000068f0788
RIP=0x000000006c7252f7, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000014487df0)
0x0000000014487df0:   0000000006928390 000000001e27b9d0
0x0000000014487e00:   000007ffffe203a0 00000000069282b0
0x0000000014487e10:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000014487e20:   0000000010d4b910 0000000100000000
0x0000000014487e30:   0000000000000000 00000000000c7bf3
0x0000000014487e40:   0000000000000000 0000000000000010
0x0000000014487e50:   c1dfffffffc00000 000000002201a070
0x0000000014487e60:   00000000068f0750 000000000000000d
0x0000000014487e70:   00000000068f0788 000000002201a268
0x0000000014487e80:   c1dfffffffc00000 0000000000000000
0x0000000014487e90:   41dfffffffc00000 0000000000000000
0x0000000014487ea0:   c1dfffffffc00000 0000000000000000
0x0000000014487eb0:   41dfffffffc00000 0000000000000000
0x0000000014487ec0:   c1dfffffffc00000 0000000000000000
0x0000000014487ed0:   41dfffffffc00000 0000000000000000
0x0000000014487ee0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000006c7252f7)
0x000000006c7252d7:   48 85 d2 74 34 44 0f b6 72 03 41 f6 c6 01 75 29
0x000000006c7252e7:   41 83 ce 01 4c 8b 42 10 44 88 72 03 4c 8b 72 18
0x000000006c7252f7:   4d 89 46 10 4d 89 70 18 44 8b 43 20 48 89 42 10
0x000000006c725307:   41 83 f8 ff 74 18 48 89 d0 41 83 c3 01 49 83 c4 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000021f6ebd8 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000000221e2f30 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000001e28fb70 is an unknown value
RSP=0x0000000014487df0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000012b64000
RBP=0x00000000068f0788 is an unknown value
RSI=0x000000006c9dc2c0 is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000006c95da70 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R12=0x00000000221e2f38 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000006c95db40 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x00000000068f0788 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000013c90000,0x0000000014490000],  sp=0x0000000014487df0,  free space=8159k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [R.dll+0x252f7]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.rniEval(JJ)J+0
j  org.rosuda.REngine.JRI.JRIEngine.eval(Lorg/rosuda/REngine/REXP;Lorg/rosuda/REngine/REXP;Z)Lorg/rosuda/REngine/REXP;+166
j  org.rosuda.REngine.REngine.parseAndEval(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/rosuda/REngine/REXP;Z)Lorg/rosuda/REngine/REXP;+13
j  org.nlogo.extension.r.HoldRengineX.execute(Lorg/rosuda/REngine/REngine;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/rosuda/REngine/REXP;Z)Lorg/rosuda/REngine/REXP;+28
j  org.nlogo.extension.r.Entry$Eval.perform([Lorg/nlogo/api/Argument;Lorg/nlogo/api/Context;)V+24
j  org.nlogo.prim._extern.perform(Lorg/nlogo/nvm/Context;)V+60
J 2544 C2 org.nlogo.nvm.ExclusiveJob.run()V (126 bytes) @ 0x0000000002b6f6ec [0x0000000002b6f3e0+0x30c]
J 2776 C2 org.nlogo.nvm.Context.runExclusiveJob(Lorg/nlogo/agent/AgentSet;I)V (54 bytes) @ 0x0000000002bec498 [0x0000000002bec380+0x118]
j  org.nlogo.prim._asm_procedurecalchomerange_ask_4.perform(Lorg/nlogo/nvm/Context;)V+288
j  org.nlogo.nvm.Context.stepConcurrent()V+64
j  org.nlogo.nvm.ConcurrentJob.step()V+64
j  org.nlogo.job.JobThread.org$nlogo$job$JobThread$$runPrimaryJobs()V+347
j  org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp()V+29
j  org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply()V+1
j  org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Lscala/Function0;)Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  org.nlogo.util.Exceptions$.handling(Lscala/collection/Seq;Lscala/Function0;)V+18
j  org.nlogo.job.JobThread.run()V+29
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000001496d800 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=4396, stack(0x0000000020ef0000,0x0000000020ff0000)]
  0x000000001496d000 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=5444, stack(0x000000001a4f0000,0x000000001a5f0000)]
  0x0000000014bd4000 JavaThread "BehaviorSpace Worker" [_thread_blocked, id=2296, stack(0x000000001d870000,0x000000001d970000)]
  0x0000000014bd3800 JavaThread "BehaviorSpace Supervisor" [_thread_blocked, id=1960, stack(0x000000001eb70000,0x000000001ec70000)]
  0x0000000014bd2800 JavaThread "JobThread" [_thread_blocked, id=5128, stack(0x0000000020630000,0x0000000020e30000)]
  0x0000000014bd2000 JavaThread "JobThread" [_thread_blocked, id=4200, stack(0x000000001fdf0000,0x00000000205f0000)]
  0x0000000014bd1000 JavaThread "JobThread" [_thread_blocked, id=5192, stack(0x000000001f500000,0x000000001fd00000)]
  0x0000000014bd0000 JavaThread "JobThread" [_thread_blocked, id=3876, stack(0x000000001ec70000,0x000000001f470000)]
  0x0000000014bcf800 JavaThread "JobThread" [_thread_blocked, id=6912, stack(0x000000001e2c0000,0x000000001eac0000)]
  0x0000000014bce800 JavaThread "JobThread" [_thread_blocked, id=6652, stack(0x000000001da50000,0x000000001e250000)]
  0x0000000014bce000 JavaThread "JobThread" [_thread_blocked, id=3116, stack(0x000000001d060000,0x000000001d860000)]
  0x0000000014bcd000 JavaThread "Thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=816, stack(0x000000001ad60000,0x000000001ae60000)]
  0x000000001516c000 JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2044, stack(0x000000001a960000,0x000000001aa60000)]
  0x000000000213d800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=7040, stack(0x0000000002500000,0x0000000002600000)]
  0x0000000012aea000 JavaThread "Lifeguard" [_thread_blocked, id=3644, stack(0x0000000014800000,0x0000000014900000)]
  0x0000000012b01800 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6748, stack(0x0000000014510000,0x0000000014610000)]
=>0x0000000012b64000 JavaThread "JobThread" [_thread_in_native, id=4264, stack(0x0000000013c90000,0x0000000014490000)]
  0x000000001288e800 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=3564, stack(0x00000000135b0000,0x00000000136b0000)]
  0x00000000127af000 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5152, stack(0x00000000132d0000,0x00000000133d0000)]
  0x00000000127ae800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=4732, stack(0x0000000013000000,0x0000000013100000)]
  0x00000000127a0000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6000, stack(0x00000000120f0000,0x00000000121f0000)]
  0x000000000fa8e800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5224, stack(0x0000000012490000,0x0000000012590000)]
  0x000000000fa8b800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5044, stack(0x00000000122f0000,0x00000000123f0000)]
  0x000000000fa84000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1384, stack(0x00000000121f0000,0x00000000122f0000)]
  0x000000000fa83000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3960, stack(0x0000000011f90000,0x0000000012090000)]
  0x000000000fa82800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6316, stack(0x0000000011be0000,0x0000000011ce0000)]
  0x000000000fa71000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3424, stack(0x0000000011e90000,0x0000000011f90000)]
  0x0000000002236800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1448, stack(0x0000000011cf0000,0x0000000011df0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000000fa6d800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000011ae0000,0x0000000011be0000] [id=5788]
  0x000000000fa8f000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000012620000,0x0000000012720000] [id=6516]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 755712K, used 203842K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007e0400000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 665088K, 28% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007b6347db8,0x00000007d3400000)
  from space 90624K, 16% used [0x00000007d3400000,0x00000007d4248af8,0x00000007d8c80000)
  to   space 86528K, 0% used [0x00000007daf80000,0x00000007daf80000,0x00000007e0400000)
 ParOldGen       total 447488K, used 331809K [0x0000000700000000, 0x000000071b500000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 447488K, 74% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000714408628,0x000000071b500000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 81937K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000)
  object space 83968K, 97% used [0x00000006fae00000,0x00000006ffe04558,0x0000000700000000)

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000005600000,0x0000000005e30000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000001e29000

Polling page: 0x0000000000130000

Code Cache  [0x0000000002600000, 0x0000000002c40000, 0x0000000005600000)
 total_blobs=3394 nmethods=2789 adapters=557 free_code_cache=42880Kb largest_free_block=43786304

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 216.538 Thread 0x000000000fa8b800 2939             org.nlogo.prim._asm_procedureestablishorupdatemalehomerange_myself_218::report (38 bytes)
Event: 216.538 Thread 0x000000000fa84000 2940             org.nlogo.prim._asm_procedureestablishorupdatemalehomerange_self_216::report (5 bytes)
Event: 216.538 Thread 0x000000000fa84000 nmethod 2940 0x0000000002bd6fd0 code [0x0000000002bd7100, 0x0000000002bd7178]
Event: 216.542 Thread 0x000000000fa8b800 nmethod 2939 0x0000000002c2b350 code [0x0000000002c2b4a0, 0x0000000002c2b5b8]
Event: 216.768 Thread 0x000000000fa84000 2941   !         org.rosuda.REngine.JRI.JRIEngine::resolvePointer (1116 bytes)
Event: 216.796 Thread 0x000000000fa8b800 2942  s          org.rosuda.JRI.Mutex::safeLock (70 bytes)
Event: 216.802 Thread 0x000000000fa8b800 nmethod 2942 0x0000000002c1ec10 code [0x0000000002c1ed80, 0x0000000002c1f348]
Event: 216.825 Thread 0x000000000fa8b800 2943             org.nlogo.extension.r.HoldRengineX::resolveListAndVector (251 bytes)
Event: 216.839 Thread 0x000000000fa8b800 nmethod 2943 0x0000000002bf8cd0 code [0x0000000002bf8e80, 0x0000000002bf93a8]
Event: 216.855 Thread 0x000000000fa8b800 2944             org.nlogo.extension.r.HoldRengineX::resolveListAndVector (251 bytes)

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 208.053 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=22 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 673792K, used 568320K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007da480000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 568320K, 100% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007cd580000,0x00000007cd580000)
  from space 105472K, 0% used [0x00000007d3d80000,0x00000007d3d80000,0x00000007da480000)
  to   space 105984K, 0% used [0x00000007cd580000,0x00000007cd580000,0x00000007d3d00000)
 ParOldGen       total 447488K, used 331801K [0x0000000700000000, 0x000000071b500000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 447488K, 74% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000714406628,0x000000071b500000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 81658K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000)
  object space 83968K, 97% used [0x00000006fae00000,0x00000006ffdbe8a0,0x0000000700000000)
Event: 208.087 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=22 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 674304K, used 23844K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007ddb80000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 568320K, 0% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007cd580000)
  from space 105984K, 22% used [0x00000007cd580000,0x00000007cecc9370,0x00000007d3d00000)
  to   space 100864K, 0% used [0x00000007d7900000,0x00000007d7900000,0x00000007ddb80000)
 ParOldGen       total 447488K, used 331801K [0x0000000700000000, 0x000000071b500000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 447488K, 74% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000714406628,0x000000071b500000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 81658K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000)
  object space 83968K, 97% used [0x00000006fae00000,0x00000006ffdbe8a0,0x0000000700000000)
}
Event: 209.309 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=23 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 674304K, used 592164K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007ddb80000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 568320K, 100% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007cd580000,0x00000007cd580000)
  from space 105984K, 22% used [0x00000007cd580000,0x00000007cecc9370,0x00000007d3d00000)
  to   space 100864K, 0% used [0x00000007d7900000,0x00000007d7900000,0x00000007ddb80000)
 ParOldGen       total 447488K, used 331801K [0x0000000700000000, 0x000000071b500000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 447488K, 74% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000714406628,0x000000071b500000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 81671K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000)
  object space 83968K, 97% used [0x00000006fae00000,0x00000006ffdc1df8,0x0000000700000000)
Event: 209.325 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=23 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 715264K, used 10486K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007dce80000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 627712K, 0% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007d0f80000)
  from space 87552K, 11% used [0x00000007d7900000,0x00000007d833db58,0x00000007dce80000)
  to   space 97792K, 0% used [0x00000007d0f80000,0x00000007d0f80000,0x00000007d6f00000)
 ParOldGen       total 447488K, used 331801K [0x0000000700000000, 0x000000071b500000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 447488K, 74% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000714406628,0x000000071b500000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 81671K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000)
  object space 83968K, 97% used [0x00000006fae00000,0x00000006ffdc1df8,0x0000000700000000)
}
Event: 214.069 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=24 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 715264K, used 637997K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007dce80000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 627712K, 99% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007d0f4dbf0,0x00000007d0f80000)
  from space 87552K, 11% used [0x00000007d7900000,0x00000007d833db58,0x00000007dce80000)
  to   space 97792K, 0% used [0x00000007d0f80000,0x00000007d0f80000,0x00000007d6f00000)
 ParOldGen       total 447488K, used 331801K [0x0000000700000000, 0x000000071b500000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 447488K, 74% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000714406628,0x000000071b500000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 81866K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000)
  object space 83968K, 97% used [0x00000006fae00000,0x00000006ffdf29a8,0x0000000700000000)
Event: 214.090 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=24 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 725504K, used 14065K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007dfc00000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 627712K, 0% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007d0f80000)
  from space 97792K, 14% used [0x00000007d0f80000,0x00000007d1d3c480,0x00000007d6f00000)
  to   space 94208K, 0% used [0x00000007da000000,0x00000007da000000,0x00000007dfc00000)
 ParOldGen       total 447488K, used 331809K [0x0000000700000000, 0x000000071b500000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 447488K, 74% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000714408628,0x000000071b500000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 81866K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000)
  object space 83968K, 97% used [0x00000006fae00000,0x00000006ffdf29a8,0x0000000700000000)
}
Event: 214.863 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=25 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 725504K, used 641777K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007dfc00000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 627712K, 100% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007d0f80000,0x00000007d0f80000)
  from space 97792K, 14% used [0x00000007d0f80000,0x00000007d1d3c480,0x00000007d6f00000)
  to   space 94208K, 0% used [0x00000007da000000,0x00000007da000000,0x00000007dfc00000)
 ParOldGen       total 447488K, used 331809K [0x0000000700000000, 0x000000071b500000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 447488K, 74% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000714408628,0x000000071b500000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 81884K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000)
  object space 83968K, 97% used [0x00000006fae00000,0x00000006ffdf70b0,0x0000000700000000)
Event: 214.881 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=25 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 735744K, used 13883K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007de500000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 665088K, 0% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007d3400000)
  from space 70656K, 19% used [0x00000007da000000,0x00000007dad8ee40,0x00000007de500000)
  to   space 90624K, 0% used [0x00000007d3400000,0x00000007d3400000,0x00000007d8c80000)
 ParOldGen       total 447488K, used 331809K [0x0000000700000000, 0x000000071b500000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 447488K, 74% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000714408628,0x000000071b500000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 81884K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000)
  object space 83968K, 97% used [0x00000006fae00000,0x00000006ffdf70b0,0x0000000700000000)
}
Event: 215.684 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=26 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 735744K, used 678971K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007de500000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 665088K, 100% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007d3400000,0x00000007d3400000)
  from space 70656K, 19% used [0x00000007da000000,0x00000007dad8ee40,0x00000007de500000)
  to   space 90624K, 0% used [0x00000007d3400000,0x00000007d3400000,0x00000007d8c80000)
 ParOldGen       total 447488K, used 331809K [0x0000000700000000, 0x000000071b500000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 447488K, 74% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000714408628,0x000000071b500000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 81920K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000)
  object space 83968K, 97% used [0x00000006fae00000,0x00000006ffe000f0,0x0000000700000000)
Event: 215.701 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=26 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 755712K, used 14626K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007e0400000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 665088K, 0% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007d3400000)
  from space 90624K, 16% used [0x00000007d3400000,0x00000007d4248af8,0x00000007d8c80000)
  to   space 86528K, 0% used [0x00000007daf80000,0x00000007daf80000,0x00000007e0400000)
 ParOldGen       total 447488K, used 331809K [0x0000000700000000, 0x000000071b500000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 447488K, 74% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000714408628,0x000000071b500000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 81920K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700000000)
  object space 83968K, 97% used [0x00000006fae00000,0x00000006ffe000f0,0x0000000700000000)
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 213.612 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002a670f0 method=org.nlogo.nvm.Task$class.bindArgs(Lorg/nlogo/nvm/Task;Lorg/nlogo/nvm/Context;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V @ 6
Event: 213.612 Thread 0x0000000014bce000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002a670f0 method=org.nlogo.nvm.Task$class.bindArgs(Lorg/nlogo/nvm/Task;Lorg/nlogo/nvm/Context;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V @ 6
Event: 213.613 Thread 0x0000000014bce000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002a670f0 method=org.nlogo.nvm.Task$class.bindArgs(Lorg/nlogo/nvm/Task;Lorg/nlogo/nvm/Context;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V @ 6
Event: 213.613 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002a670f0 method=org.nlogo.nvm.Task$class.bindArgs(Lorg/nlogo/nvm/Task;Lorg/nlogo/nvm/Context;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V @ 6
Event: 213.798 Thread 0x000000001496d800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000271f960 method=scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$HashUtils$class.elemHashCode(Lscala/collection/mutable/HashTable$HashUtils;Ljava/lang/Object;)I @ 18
Event: 213.818 Thread 0x000000001288e800 Uncommon trap: reason=unreached action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002899b34 method=java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.finishedDispatching(Z)V @ 9
Event: 216.419 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002c02e20 method=org.nlogo.agent.InRadiusOrCone.inRadius(Lorg/nlogo/agent/Agent;Lorg/nlogo/agent/AgentSet;DZ)Ljava/util/List; @ 64
Event: 216.420 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002c02e20 method=org.nlogo.agent.InRadiusOrCone.inRadius(Lorg/nlogo/agent/Agent;Lorg/nlogo/agent/AgentSet;DZ)Ljava/util/List; @ 64
Event: 216.431 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002c02e20 method=org.nlogo.agent.InRadiusOrCone.inRadius(Lorg/nlogo/agent/Agent;Lorg/nlogo/agent/AgentSet;DZ)Ljava/util/List; @ 64
Event: 216.432 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002c02e20 method=org.nlogo.agent.InRadiusOrCone.inRadius(Lorg/nlogo/agent/Agent;Lorg/nlogo/agent/AgentSet;DZ)Ljava/util/List; @ 64

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 210.987 Thread 0x0000000014bce000 Threw 0x00000007c3479a08 at C:\re\jdk7u65\1320\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 210.988 Thread 0x0000000014bce000 Threw 0x00000007c347bc88 at C:\re\jdk7u65\1320\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 210.988 Thread 0x0000000014bce000 Threw 0x00000007c347e660 at C:\re\jdk7u65\1320\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 210.990 Thread 0x0000000014bce000 Threw 0x00000007c3484648 at C:\re\jdk7u65\1320\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 210.991 Thread 0x0000000014bce000 Threw 0x00000007c348a7f0 at C:\re\jdk7u65\1320\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 212.208 Thread 0x0000000014bce000 Threw 0x00000007c349c428 at C:\re\jdk7u65\1320\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 213.610 Thread 0x0000000014bce000 Threw 0x00000007c4974ad8 at C:\re\jdk7u65\1320\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 213.611 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 Threw 0x00000007c4787dc8 at C:\re\jdk7u65\1320\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 213.797 Thread 0x000000001496d800 Threw 0x00000007ac2e0460 at C:\re\jdk7u65\1320\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 213.797 Thread 0x000000001496d800 Threw 0x00000007ac2e38f8 at C:\re\jdk7u65\1320\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244

Events (10 events):
Event: 216.419 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000002639064 sp=0x000000001448ec78 mode 2
Event: 216.420 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffffde fr.pc=0x0000000002c02e20
Event: 216.420 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000002c02e20 sp=0x000000001448ecf0
Event: 216.420 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000002639064 sp=0x000000001448ec78 mode 2
Event: 216.431 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffffde fr.pc=0x0000000002c02e20
Event: 216.431 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000002c02e20 sp=0x000000001448ed70
Event: 216.431 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000002639064 sp=0x000000001448ecf8 mode 2
Event: 216.432 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffffde fr.pc=0x0000000002c02e20
Event: 216.432 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000002c02e20 sp=0x000000001448ed70
Event: 216.432 Thread 0x0000000012b64000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000002639064 sp=0x000000001448ecf8 mode 2


VM Arguments:
java_command: NetLogo.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64
USERNAME=ncarter
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 21 Model 1 Stepping 2, AuthenticAMD



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 21 model 1 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, mmxext, 3dnowpref, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 16776760k(12343996k free), swap 33551656k(28878624k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_65-b20), built on Jul 11 2014 00:39:37 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Tue Sep 02 15:40:40 2014
elapsed time: 216 seconds
```

Comment: You may need to take this up directly with the authors of the R extension.

Comment: @Seth Tisue. I have, but I haven't heard back from them. Not sure if it helps, but I posted the error message. I'm completely stuck on this one.