# How can I debug a NetLogo BehaviorSpace / R-extension error?

Tags: java, netlogo

I have a model that works fine interactively. However, whenever I try and run it with BehaviorSpace, I get a variety of errors.

The model uses the R extension. The general order of events is:

1. setup: creates a network, writes a file for R to import and uses either R or NetLogo to select some starting nodes
2. go: runs a contagion process from those starting nodes

It seems to work when I am using only a single processor, so I think that there is some sort of contamination between parallel processes in the R side (because each thread creates and manipulates networks with the same name for example). However, the R-extension documentation specifically states that it works with BehaviorSpace and creates a separate R environment for each NetLogo run.

The errors include:

- 'Error in ReadBin ...: can only read from a binary connection
- 'Error in isOpen(filename) : invalid connection'

These errors only occur on a few runs, and with various parameter combinations. Other runs with the same parameter combinations do not have errors.

Is there some sort of output log I can access for BehaviorSpace that I can print to, to try and isolate the problem? Ideally, I would like to pause the experiment and look at the contents of variables etc.

**UPDATED**: Here is the error log for a typical error:

> Extension exception: Error in R-Extension: Error in Eval: 
>   org.nlogo.api.ExtensionException: Error in readBin(filename, what =
>   raw(0), n = tmpbufsize) :    can only read from a binary connection
>
> error while observer running R:EVAL   called by procedure EXPORT-NW2R 
>   called by procedure SETUP   called by procedure __EVALUATOR
>
> org.nlogo.nvm.EngineException: Extension exception: Error in
>   R-Extension: Error in Eval:  org.nlogo.api.ExtensionException: Error
>   in readBin(filename, what = raw(0), n = tmpbufsize) :    can only read
>   from a binary connection
>
> at org.nlogo.extension.r.Entry$Eval.perform(Entry.java:560)  at
>   org.nlogo.prim._extern.perform(_extern.java:54)  at
>   org.nlogo.nvm.Context.stepConcurrent(Context.java:91)  at
>   org.nlogo.nvm.ConcurrentJob.step(ConcurrentJob.java:82)  at
>   org.nlogo.job.JobThread.org$nlogo$job$JobThread$$runPrimaryJobs(JobThread.scala:143)
>   at
>   org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobThread.scala:78)
>   at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobThread.scala:76) 
>   at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobThread.scala:76) 
>   at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:88)  at
>   org.nlogo.util.Exceptions$.handling(Exceptions.scala:41)  at
>   org.nlogo.job.JobThread.run(JobThread.scala:75)
>
> NetLogo 5.3 main: org.nlogo.app.AppFrame thread: JobThread Java
>   HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_65 (Oracle Corporation;
>   1.8.0_65-b17) operating system: Windows 8.1 6.3 (amd64 processor) Scala version 2.9.2 JOGL: (3D View not initialized) OpenGL Graphics:
>   (3D View not initialized) model: Interventions
>
> 03:41:43.172 JobRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1
>   (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) JobThread 03:41:43.172
>   JobRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1
>   (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) JobThread 03:41:43.172
>   JobRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1
>   (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) JobThread 03:41:43.172
>   JobRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1
>   (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) JobThread 03:41:43.172
>   JobRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1
>   (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) JobThread 03:41:43.172
>   JobRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1
>   (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) JobThread 03:41:43.172
>   JobRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1
>   (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) JobThread 03:41:43.172
>   JobRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1
>   (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) JobThread 03:41:43.172
>   JobRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1
>   (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) JobThread 03:41:43.172
>   JobRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1
>   (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) JobThread

The export-nw2r procedure looks like this:

```
to export-nw2r
  ; create file with useful graph format
  nw:set-context people links
  let filename (word "Networks/netlogo" behaviorspace-run-number ".gml")
  export-simple-gml filename

  ;; reset the R-workspace
  r:clearLocal
  let dir pathdir:get-model
  r:eval "library(igraph)"

  ; read network in R
  set filename (word dir "/" filename)
  r:put "fn" filename
  r:eval "gg <- read_graph(file = fn, format = 'gml')"
  r:eval "V(gg)$name <- V(gg)$id"          ; gml uses 'id', but igraph uses 'name'
  r:eval "if (file.exists(fn)) file.remove(fn)"
end
```

Basically, it calls a procedure to create a very simplified gml format text file (because igraph has a crippled import procedure), switches over to R and clears the R workspace, imports the graph and calculates properties.

I have run the current version of my code as a single processor BehaviorSpace experiment about 10 times without failure, and 4 times with failure on every occasion. So there appears to be a bug in the way that BehaviorSpace and the R-extension interact. Leaving this here for information, but I don't really expect a solution unless someone can interpret the java error. Appears to be the same bug as [NetLogo BehaviorSpace crashing when using R extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556485/netlogo-behaviorspace-crashing-when-using-r-extension)

Comment: You could run BehaviorSpace in a Java IDE such as IntelliJ and step through it in the debugger that way. I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Seth. I will find an actual Java programmer (which I am not) and do this, and see if we get any headway. Will report back if we do.