# Behaviour space in Netlogo crashes when using extension R

Tags: r, netlogo

I am making a simulation with NetLogo and extension R. I have made a supply chain model, where I have distributors and consumers. Consumers provide orders to distributors and distributors forecast future demand and places orders to suppliers in advance to fulfill market demand. The forecast is implemented with extension R (https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/r.html) by calling elmNN package. The model works fine when simply using "go". 
However, when I want to conduct experiments by using behavior space, I keep getting errors. If I set only a few ticks with behavior space, the model works fine. But when I want to launch a few hundred ticks behavior space keeps crashing. For example, "Extension exception: Error in R-extension: error in eval, operator is invalid for atomic vector", "Extension exception: Error in R-extension: error in eval: cannot have attributes on CHARSXP". Sometimes the behavior simply crashes without any error.

I assume that the errors are related to computability issues between NetLogo, R, R extension and java. I am using NetLogo 5.3.1, 64-bit; R-3.3.3 64-bit; rJava 0.9-8.

Model example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjQpPBgj0A8

A similar question was posted previously, but it has no answer: [NetLogo BehaviorSpace crashing when using R extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556485/netlogo-behaviorspace-crashing-when-using-r-extension)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with programming style, which is not suitable for behavior space. Behavior space supports parallel programming due to which some variables were rewritten by new information in the process. When I set Simultaneous runs in parallel to 1 in the behavior space everything was fine.